# AWS Lambda Function duration spikes caused by https connection timeouts

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I have a Flask API running on API Gateway and Lambda Functions, where my Lambda Functions are [configured to run in my VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/).

Normal duration for my Lambda Function should be about 3 seconds, but sometimes it spikes to 130 seconds or more, which causes my API Gateway to return a 504.

The Lambda Function makes a GET request using the `requests` library:

```
url = base_url + endpoint
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response = json.loads(req.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

CloudWatch shows the following error on the request that times out:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host', port=port): Max retries exceeded with url: /foo/bar (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at foo>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Most all of the posts I have read refer to an incorrectly configured Lambda Function running in a private subnet, but I know that is not my issue since my functions have access to the internet.

My other theory is that a session is getting reused on the function's underlying container, which is causing a timeout.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It might be a certificate issue. Does calling the request without TLS certificate verification look any better? requests.get(url, params=query, verify=False)

Comment: I didn't think about that - that did not seem to fix the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've set your Lambda to run in your VPC, it's quite possible that a Network ACL is not allowing the traffic.

Your described behavior would be consistent with an ephemeral port being blocked. It would cause the traffic to eventually time out, leading to somewhat random spikes in lambda runtime & a failure for seemingly unknown reasons.

I'm not even sure it would be apparent from VPC flow logs what happened, since it was the ephemeral port that was blocked, not the reserved port, but I'll have to double-check that.

AWS uses [ephemeral ports 1024 - 65535](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports). I would take a look at the Network ACLs and double-check that those ports are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible the connection you created in the first invocation of Lambda is being reused when the Lambda container is being reused in the subsequent requests. This connection may have been terminated by the server, but the Lambda container does not have an idea about it. So, it tries to make the new request on the stale connection until it times out.

Possible ways to avoid this -

**1. Manage connections appropriately**

Create the connection outside the Lambda handler function, but manage it for error handling inside the handler function. Also, consider terminating the connection  after completion of execution if your function is not being very frequently invoked.

**2. Set a timeout**

Every SDK supports a timeout value for connection termination. For example, Python has 60 seconds. That means, your Python request will try to connect on that stale connection for 60 seconds before timing out. Try setting a custom timeout value for your request (something lower so that Lambda doesn't time out) and if an error occurs, catch it and create a new connection. Read more about this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/).